# get taller advertisment

Tags: workout-routines

I have seen on internet a site that claims  you can become tall even after 25. You can take many inches. There are many fotos before and after from many humans. I search it and I find different aspects , some of them conflict but I didn't get from them a result if this is true or not. I am 22 I don't think I can increase my high but this gave me hope. Many in YouTube telling its a scam,is it? Can be a good scientific answer why it can't be this in age 25.I don't write the site but I think everyone can google it and find it. Additional to,genetics can be changing as i heard from a doctor in case you doing more than four hours a day hung up and give you few inches 2-3 ,is this true too? Workout could be used to be taller or this is a fake advertisement with only target the money.

Comment: As in the accepted answer - reduce disc compression in your back, for example weight loss if you are overweight or modifications to posture and lifestyle does work. Last summer I had been doing 1 month of muscle ups and other bar exercises which seems to did something for the disc compression I guess, because I started having some mild back pains and I also started standing more straight which increased my height by 3cm. after the yearly check at the doctor, but that was all a modification of the lifestyle and body posture/standing with a more straight back and head/neck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of programmes will have you do stretching exercises and eat food to raise HGH levels. They have no long term effect on your height whatsoever. They may have a very small effect on your height if you take measures to reduce disc compression in your back, for example weight loss if you are overweight or modifications to posture and lifestyle.